# Delphi CryptoApi pkcs#12

Tags: delphi, cryptoapi, pkcs#12

Имеется необходимость импортировать в системные сертификаты несколько сертификатов, с форматами pkcs#7 никаких проблем не возникает, чего нельзя сказать о pkcs#12..
я так понимаю связано это с возможностью хранить несколько сертификатов в одном файле, вопрос собсно в том как можно с помощью криптоапи распарсить его содержимое или в ручную и далее скормить его системе...